# How to advance the progress bar for specific operation (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, progress

my problem is, I have SQL server and i want while the user take a backup of the database, a progress bar advances as the REAL backup operation do.

for example if i have 100 tables, so, the progress bar should be advanced by 1 for each 1 table that have been backed-up.

Or, id doesn't matter per table, just simply, the progress bar advances correctly with the operation.

Thank you, the code is below..

```
try
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFile.Filter = "Backup (*.bac) | *.bac";
            progressBar1.Visible = true;

            if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                conn.Open();
                com = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE ServerDB TO DISK = '"+saveFile.FileName+"'", conn);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                progressBar1.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Your backup (" + saveFile.FileName + ") has been created successfuly", "Backup done", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: can you wire up any events to your server?

Comment: actually in this case, it is not possible to do so , let me explain why : Firstly, the task that is being done is `BACKING UP THE ENTIRE DATABASE`, it cannot be known how many tables there are so you cannot really ask your progressbar to act so :( ... But what you can do is attach the progressbar with the entire backup , if you are ok with this, then reply and i will post an answer :)

Comment: It's possible if you query `sys.dm_exec_requests` table, you can see an example here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/

Anyway, you need to do this in a separate thread, because `ExecuteNonQuery` will return only when process finishes

Comment: @zackraiyan  yes, it doesn't matter the way, just i want the progress bar to advance correctly with the backup process, which means it reach 100% by the end of back up

Answer (score 1):

Firt, a pet peeve of mine is proper Exception Handling and you have some mistakes in there: You catch Exception. You are not closing the connection via finally and thus only in the Exception case. If you want to avoid any followup problem, you really need to read up on this. Here are two articles I link often:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

As for the actuall problem:

You can only do Progress Reporting between Distinct Operations. Mostly doing the level of reporting you want is way, way more trouble then it is worth.

While some really new classes do support deep Progress Reporting, for most other cases it means you have to re-do the existing code. Often reverse-engineering it down to the lowest loop you want to do Progress reporting on. On top of that you will need some approach of Multitasking. While the long running operation has not returned, no other code on the UI thread can run. Including the code that actually dispalys any updates. I wrote some decent example code for BackgroundWorker a while back. It should get you onto the right track:

```
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
        int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
        pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
        tbPrim.Text = "";

        //Start processing
        bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
    }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
    //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
    //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
    List<int> Primes = new List<int>();


    //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
    for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
    {
        //Report progress
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
        bool isNoPrime = false;

        //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
        if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        //Determin if this is a Prime Number
        for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
        {
            if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
                isNoPrime = true;
        }

        if (!isNoPrime)
            Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
    }

    //Tell the progress bar you are finished
    thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

    //Save Return Value
    e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
    this.Refresh();

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //Show the Result
        int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int Prim in Primes)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
    }
}
#endregion
```